# How to check whether someone enters a Path directory on Windows or Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, path

Macs return a Posixpath when the user enters a path. Windows returns a WindowsPath object when the user does the same thing. Is there a way for me to check whether the input is valid depending on the machine?

Comment: "Enters a path"? What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.sep` gives you the path separator for the platform, `\\` for windows and `/` for unix.

But the thing is if you need this to implement a `if else`, then *don't* do that way. The `os.path` functions are aware of platform specific behavior and they will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, unless you are using the new `pathlib`, the thing  returned in both cases is just a `str`.

Also, NT accepts `/` as a path delimeter and to posix `\` is just another character.

So -- no, you can't tell, at least not without trying to use the path; and that will only tell you if something is wrong, not if something *can* work.